# replace the LAST ',' in a CSV with a tab?

Tags: vi

In a large and wide CSV table, how can I replace the LAST ',' with a tab in vi?  An awk command would be just as useful, but I don't know awk well enough.  (I'd do it in PERL but I don't want to write a script).

Ex. Replace the comma before the last value with a tab.  It's easy to do at the beginning of the line, but not at the end.  Any ideas?

```
chr9,5971307,…,2,2,2,2,2,0,5881595,6007901,KIAA2026,20605
chr9,5971313,…,0,0,0,0,0,0,5881595,6007901,KIAA2026,20605
chr9,5971416,…,2,2,2,2,2,0,5881595,6007901,KIAA2026,20605
```

Note: the number of CSV values is > 1000. The values are not fixed as they appear above, so I cannot rely on the data or a fixed column number.  This is dependent on the field separators (,).

Thanks for any help you can supply.
Cheers,
Joe White

Comment: Do you mean the last comma on each line?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `substitute` command.

```
:%s/,\ze[^,]*$/\t
```

The `\ze` piece will cause everything after it (that is, the `[^,]*$`) to not get replaced, but it still needs to match. So this means:

- `:%s/` Substitute on every line...
- `,` a comma
- `\ze` Followed by, (but don't replace this part)
- `[^,]*` Any number of characters that *aren't* commas.
- `$` and then the end of the line
- `/` *with*
- `\t` a tab.

This is effectively the same as

```
:%s/,\([^,]*\)$/\t\1
```

You could also do this with a normal mode command, but this will not work if the last character on a line is a comma.

```
:%norm $F,r<C-v><tab>
```

(Note that `<C-v>` means <kbd>ctrl-v</kbd> and `<tab>` means a literal tab character)